# Subtract/Add days to a predefined date using Write-Host

Tags: date, powershell, variables, tostring, write-host

I am trying to display milestones. I tried below but I get an error that displays `Method invocation failed because [System.String] does  not contain a method named 'AddDays'.` I have predefined `$lastmodified` in a previous line and it is `12/28/2015 0:00`

```
$predetermined=[system.datetime]$LastModified
$date= ($predetermined).AddDays(30).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy:")

$date5 = ($date).AddDays(-15).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy:")
$date4 = ($date).AddDays(-12).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy:")
$date3 = ($date).AddDays(-9).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy:")
$date2 = ($date).AddDays(-6).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy:")
$date1 = ($date).AddDays(-3).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy:")

write-host -foregroundcolor Green "$date5 Action 1"
write-host -foregroundcolor Green "$date4 Action 2"
write-host -foregroundcolor Green "$date3 Action 3"
write-host -foregroundcolor Green "$date2 Action 4"
write-host -foregroundcolor Green "$date1 Action 5"
write-host -foregroundcolor Green "$date Action 6"
```

My output should say

```
12/23/2015: Action 1"
12/26/2015: Action 2"
12/19/2015: Action 3"
12/22/2015: Action 4"
12/25/2015: Action 5"
12/28/2015: Action 6"
```

Comment: Your `$date` is string, because you call `ToString("MM/dd/yyyy:")` yourself. And string does not have `AddDays` method.

Comment: That did it. I removed the string part:
       `$date5 = ($date).AddDays(-15) 
        $date4 = ($date).AddDays(-12)
        $date3 = ($date).AddDays(-9)
        $date2 = ($date).AddDays(-6)
        $date1 = ($date).AddDays(-3)`

 but is there a way to format the answers because the outputs are all going off of `$lastmodified` which is in the format 12/28/2015 0:00. Maybe add -d at the end

Comment: Keep variables, which you use in `datetime` arithmetic, as `datetime`. And use `ToString` for variables, which you want to display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this in your code:

```
function Get-DateFmt1
{
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
        [DateTime] $Date
    )

    $Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
}

$LastModified = [DateTime]::Parse('12/28/2015')
# ....
$predetermined=[DateTime]$LastModified
$date = ($predetermined).AddDays(30)

$date5 = $date.AddDays(-15)
$date4 = $date.AddDays(-12)
$date3 = $date.AddDays(-9)
$date2 = $date.AddDays(-6)
$date1 = $date.AddDays(-3)

Write-Host -Foregroundcolor Green "$($date5.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")): Action 1"
Write-Host -Foregroundcolor Green "$($date4.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")): Action 2"
Write-Host -Foregroundcolor Green "$($date3.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")): Action 3"
# or write a helper function if that makes sense to you
Write-Host -Foregroundcolor Green "$(Get-DateFmt1 $date2): Action 4"
Write-Host -Foregroundcolor Green "$(Get-DateFmt1 $date1): Action 5"
Write-Host -Foregroundcolor Green "$(Get-DateFmt1 $date): Action 6"
```

Comment: Thank you I like this way better. Its a lot cleaner.

Comment: This answer doesn't explain why his code wasn't working.

Comment: Technically, the OP's question, actually has no question. It is unclear whether the OP wanted an explanation of how PowerShell works, or to be shown working code for more investigation an self-learning.

Answer (score 2):

The error is right in front of you: Method invocation failed because **[System.String] does  not contain a method named 'AddDays'**

You are trying to use `AddDays()` which is a method in the `DateTime`-class, but `$date` is not a `DateTime`-object because you turned it into a string

```
$date= ($predetermined).AddDays(30).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy:")
```

You need to keep `$date` as a `DateTime`-object if you aregoing to use it to create the other variables. Ex:

```
$predetermined=[system.datetime](get-date)
$date = $predetermined.AddDays(30)

$date5 = $date.AddDays(-15).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy:")
$date4 = $date.AddDays(-12).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy:")
$date3 = $date.AddDays(-9).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy:")
$date2 = $date.AddDays(-6).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy:")
$date1 = $date.AddDays(-3).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy:")
#Convert `$date` to string using specified format
$date0 = $date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy:")

write-host -foregroundcolor Green "$date5 Action 1"
write-host -foregroundcolor Green "$date4 Action 2"
write-host -foregroundcolor Green "$date3 Action 3"
write-host -foregroundcolor Green "$date2 Action 4"
write-host -foregroundcolor Green "$date1 Action 5"
write-host -foregroundcolor Green "$date0 Action 6"
```

**UPDATE**: Steps to troubleshoot.. The error you received included more then just the message. It also said which line caused the error.

```
Method invocation failed because [System.String] does not contain a method named 'AddDays'.
At line:4 char:1
+ $date5 = ($date).AddDays(-15).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy:")
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

It also said that `AddDays()` is not a method in `System.String`, so then we look at what you object you called `AddDays()` on:

```
($date).AddDays(-15)...
```

This means `$date` is a string-object. Now why is that? That's because it contains the result from of a `ToString()`-method.

```
$date= ($predetermined).AddDays(30).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy:")
```

Comment: I noticed after someone commented. I corrected it as stated. I just needed a second pair of eyes. Also I did not know what `[System.String] does not contain a method named 'AddDays'` meant in reference to my code and why it was displayed.

Comment: The fact that you didn't know why you got the error tells me that you didn't spend enough time troubleshooting yourself to be honest. See updated answer for explanation.